# How to handle an inconsistent markup using Scrapy selectors?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to get “Play by play” information from website:

http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/showgame?gamecode=197&seasoncode=E2015#!playbyplay

Tricky markup code:

```
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Def Rebound</td>
        <td>13 - 13</td>
        <td>Zalgiris Kaunas</td>
        <td>VECVAGARS, KASPARS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="play">
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Two Pointer</td>
        <td>15 - 13</td>
        <td>Zalgiris Kaunas</td>
        <td>VECVAGARS, KASPARS</td>
    </tr>
```

When points are made in the game it uses :

> `<tr class="play">`

instead :

> `<tr>`

...to separate information visually. I want to get “event after event” and my code that I am using can’t handle this:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="wp-field wp-field-content table-responsive"]//div/table/tbody/tr'):
    item['Minute'] = sel.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract()
```

The result that I am recieving is:

```
{'Event': [u'Def Rebound'],
 'Minute': [u'19'],
 'Player': [u'KIRILENKO, ANDREI'],
 'Res_h': [u'31 - 38'],
 'Res_v': [u'31 - 38'],
 'Team_player': [u'CSKA Moscow']}

{'Event': [],
 'Minute': [],
 'Player': [],
 'Res_h': [],
 'Res_v': [],
 'Team_player': []}
```

Empty values appears when code has to deal with "play" class for "tr".

**Question:**

How I could do it, when I have two possible markup options that accures in a certain random situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get all you want:

```
In [53]: l=['Event',                               
 'Minute',
 'Player',
 'Res_h',
 'Res_v', 'Team_player']

In [54]: table = r.xpath("//table[@class='table']")

In [55]: for tr in table.xpath(".//tr[position() > 1]"):
           assert dict(zip(l, tr.xpath("./td//text()").extract()))  != {}

....:     
In [56]:
```

It skips the header row and pulls all the rest, the order of the elements in l is wrong but the idea is correct so I will leave you to figure out what you want and where, this is a snippet of  what is returned by `tr.xpath("./td//text()"`:

```
[u'15', u'Shot Rejected', u'29 - 25', u'Zalgiris Kaunas', u'HANLAN, OLIVIER']
[u'15', u'Block', u'29 - 25', u'Real Madrid', u'NOCIONI, ANDRES']
[u'15', u'Off Rebound', u'29 - 25', u'Zalgiris Kaunas', u' ']
[u'15', u'Two Pointer', u'31 - 25', u'Zalgiris Kaunas', u'VENE, SIIM-SANDER']
[u'15', u'Assist', u'31 - 25', u'Zalgiris Kaunas', u'RANDLE, JEROME']
[u'16', u'Minute', u'31 - 25', u' ', u' ']
[u'16', u'Three Pointer', u'31 - 28', u'Real Madrid', u'NOCIONI, ANDRES']
[u'16', u'Assist', u'31 - 28', u'Real Madrid', u'LLULL, SERGIO']
[u'16', u'Two Pointer', u'33 - 28', u'Zalgiris Kaunas', u'RANDLE, JEROME']
[u'16', u'Foul', u'33 - 28', u'Zalgiris Kaunas', u'SAJUS, MARTYNAS']
[u'16', u'Foul Drawn', u'33 - 28', u'Real Madrid', u'LLULL, SERGIO']
[u'16', u'Free Throw In', u'33 - 29', u'Real Madrid', u'LLULL, SERGIO']
[u'16', u'Free Throw In', u'33 - 30', u'Real Madrid', u'LLULL, SERGIO']
[u'16', u'In', u'33 - 30', u'Zalgiris Kaunas', u'JANKUNAS, PAULIUS']
```